# React Native Android with multiple flavors does not start its Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, react-native

Building a white label application. One react-native source with multiple android flavors and iOS targets.

All is building great and installing correctly, but the application doesn't start in the debug and cannot be started in both smartphone and emulator.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 5s
258 actionable tasks: 258 executed
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "0039227690"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.xxx.A/com.xxx.MainActivity }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.xxx.A/com.xxx.MainActivity} does not exist.
```

Exausted my options. In need of some light.

react-native@0.63.2

Followed mainly those great articles:
https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/react-native-white-label-101-163c1967c12a
https://medium.com/@najera.sean/react-native-white-label-102-aba9c56f385c

\android\app\BUCK

```
android_build_config(
  name = "build_config",
  package = "com.xxx",
)

android_resource(
  name = "res",
  package = "com.xxx",
  res = "src/main/res",
)
```

\android\app\build.gradle

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xxx"
    minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
    targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
    versionCode 300000
    versionName "3.0.0"
}

flavorDimensions "default"
productFlavors {
    A {
        applicationIdSuffix ".A"
        resValue "string", "white_label_app_name", "A"
    }

    B {
        applicationIdSuffix ".B"
        resValue "string", "white_label_app_name", "B"
    }
}
```

\android\app\src\debug\java\com\xxx\ReactNativeFlipper.java

```
package com.xxx;
```

\android\app\src\A\java\com\xxx\XxxConfig.java

```
package com.xxx;
import com.xxx.R;
```

\android\app\src\B\java\com\xxx\XxxConfig.java

```
package com.xxx;
import com.xxx.R;
```

\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.xxx">
```

\android\app\src\main\java\com\xxx\XxxConfigPackage.java

```
package com.xxx;
```

\android\app\src\main\java\com\xxx\MainActivity.java

```
package com.xxx;
```

\android\app\src\main\java\com\xxx\MainApplication.java

```
package com.xxx;
```

Finally, I can execute the build with these npm scripts:

```
"A:ios": "react-native run-ios --scheme 'A'",
"B:ios": "react-native run-ios --scheme 'B'",
"A:android": "react-native run-android --variant ADebug --appIdSuffix A",
"B:android": "react-native run-android --variant BDebug --appIdSuffix B",
```

## EDIT 1

If I try to run from **Android Studio** I get "MainActivity not found". I'm messing around trying to have some hint. Looks like the packages are not configured as they should.

Comment: I am having the same issue. are you able to solve it? @tacitomv

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
adb shell am start -n com.myapp.beta/com.myapp.MainActivity
```

as it is explained here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12480